# Are there any tutorials for transitioning from Gazebo Sim to Webots?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, webots, ros-humble, urdf

Are there any decent/recommended tutorials around for transitioning to webots from gazebo Sim? Or at least setting up existing ROS 2 robots in webots?

I got a bit sick of trying to get the latest version of Gazebo working with Ros 2 Humble properly (ros2_control didn't seem to want to work at all) so I decided to give Webots a try and I'm loving it so far. But I'm still trying to get my head around how it all goes together since it seems very different to how a robot is integrated using Gazebo. Particularly getting velocity controllers working so I can get my cmd_vels into the Webots sim.

I have most of the samples working, but most of them seem to have the robot constructed in Webots and just interfacing with ROS 2 rather than importing everything through the ROS 2 Xacro pathway.

Any recommendations for resources on this area of ROS 2 and Webots?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are some resources available that can help you transition from Gazebo to Webots or set up existing ROS 2 robots in Webots.

Firstly, the official ROS 2 documentation has a tutorial on how to set up a basic Webots simulation with ROS 2, which can be found at https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots.html. This tutorial provides step-by-step instructions on how to set up a simple Webots simulation and interface it with ROS 2.

Additionally, the `webots_ros2` package has several resources available that could be helpful. As you mentioned, there are some examples available that show how to use Webots with other ROS 2 packages like `ros2_control`, `cartographer`, etc. `webots_ros2_universal_robot` shows how to import your robot from a Xacro file and use it in the Webots simulation.

Moreover, the `webots_ros2` wiki page contains explanations on the examples and how to use them. There are also more advanced tutorials that cover a range of topics, including how to set up an existing ROS 2 robot in Webots. These pages can be accessed at https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/wiki.

We are currently working on moving these wiki pages to the official ROS 2 documentation for more visibility.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*

Comment: Ah thanks for that Yannick, I managed to figure out how to get the controllers working with imported urdf files with the universal_robot example but I haven't managed to get physics working for my differential robot (I have asked this in a [new question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24578/how-do-i-make-a-robot-imported-using-urdf-and-ros2-gravity-it-just-floats) )